# How to set system admin password for SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I understand this should be searched online. I did but most of the links point to SSMS and UI for doing this. I am relying on Visual Studio 2012 SSDT and self-typed SQL query.

Please help me with below SQL command to set `sa` password.

```
 CREATE LOGIN [sa]
 WITH PASSWORD = N'MyPassword', DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [us_english];
 GO 

 ALTER LOGIN [sa] ENABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really helps if you post whatever error you are getting.

`sa` should already exist so you can't create it again. You can change it's password with this if you have sufficient privileges. If you have an error post it.

```
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD=N'NewPassword'
```

Comment: Thank you, but using above query I get `SQL:46010 incorrect syntax near PASSWORD`

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Use `SELECT @@VERSION` to find out

Comment: ahhhhh. I coped that code directly from the help file and it put in dodgy quote characters.... copy it again now.

Comment: Correct, N is not mandatory. It indicates it's a unicode string. It's certainly worth getting into the habit of using it.